# how to split a sentence into letters and store as a String array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexof

I found this on the Internet:

`char[] characters = "this is a test".ToCharArray();`

but this stores is into a `char` array. I would like to be able to store it into a `String` array because of the function I use after it only works with a `String`.

Or is there another way to put all the letters in an array and then select the index of an array where the value is the same as the letter out of the array.

Like this:

`String[] alphabet = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", " "};`

Now the first letter of the `char[]` will be `"t"`.

Now what I need is the index: 19 to be stored in a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string[] arr = "this is a test".Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

to store the indexes you don't need this `alphabet` array

```
int[] indexes = "this is a test".Select(c => (int)(c-'a')).ToArray();
```

---

You can see the output in LinqPad

[image]

This is the way, most similar to your question, but I don't think using `IndexOf` n times is a good solution

```
List<char> alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  ".ToList();
int[] arr = "this is a test".Select(c => alphabet.IndexOf(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! instantly fixed what i needed :). dont know if the question was a bit stupid but i just started c# 2 days ago. Thanks again.

Comment: @L.B was one of those times that we have updated at the same time ... I will add it again.